# Nested Query Possible

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following that works like a charm.

```
SELECT d.decisionName, c.firstname, c.lastname, o.name AS organization_name, s.parent_session_id
    FROM tblDecisions d
        INNER JOIN tblSessions s ON s.decision_id = d.decisionid
        INNER JOIN tblCounselors c ON s.counselor_ck = c.campusid
        INNER JOIN tblCounselor_to_organization co ON co.counselor_id = c.counselorid
        INNER JOIN tblOrganizations o ON o.organizationid = co.organization_id
    AND s.start_time >= '2011-01-01 00:00:00'
    AND s.is_complete = TRUE
    ORDER BY s.start_time, s.last_name, s.first_name
```

The field `parent_session_id` (integer) can store the primary ID of a previous record, otherwise it defaults to 0. What I would like to do, if possible, is to use nested or subqueries for the following:

1. Retrieve all the above, but remove any record if it's primary ID is being used by another  in the parent_session_id field.
2. If multiple records reference the same record in parent_session_id field (`> 0`), only get the latest one by time stamp (`s.start_time DESC LIMIT 1`)

I have a feeling this won't be possible without making the query ridiculously complex, but my query skills don't get much deeper than what I have above.

Comment: Aren't your two issues mutually exclusive?  The first one you don't want any records where parent_Session_ID is being used.  In the 2nd, you want the latest one if multiple are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the second question contradicts the first. The first is saying, in essence, if this session is parent to any others, don't include it in the results. The second question is saying, if more than one session has the same parent, only include the latest child.

Here is my solution incorporating both subquestions:

```
SELECT d.decisionName, c.firstname, c.lastname, o.name AS organization_name,  s.parent_session_id
, s.start_time, (SELECT max(start_time)
                      FROM tblSessions s2
                      WHERE s2.parent_session_id = s.parent_session_id)
FROM tblDecisions d
    INNER JOIN tblSessions s ON s.decision_id = d.decisionid
    INNER JOIN tblCounselors c ON s.counselor_ck = c.campusid
    INNER JOIN tblCounselor_to_organization co ON co.counselor_id = c.counselorid
    INNER JOIN tblOrganizations o ON o.organizationid = co.organization_id
AND s.start_time >= '2011-01-01 00:00:00'
AND s.is_complete = 1
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   tblSessions s1
  WHERE  s1.parent_session_id = s.sessionid
  )
AND (
     (s.parent_session_id IS NULL)
  OR (s.start_time = (SELECT max(start_time)
                      FROM tblSessions s2
                      WHERE s2.parent_session_id = s.parent_session_id))) 

ORDER BY s.start_time, s.last_name, s.first_name
```

#### [Here is an SQLFiddle demonstrating it.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68247/12)

Note that I used SQL Server, not MySQL. But
I believe the solution to be easily convertible; I think only the **is_complete = 1** needs to change to **is_complete = true**.

Comment: You understand both questions well! It took me a long time to actually type them in without trying to sound contradictory.

Comment: So far your sql is holding up well. Just need to implement it into the code base.

Answer (score 2):

> 1.) Retrieve all the above, but remove any record if it's primary ID is being used by another in the parent_session_id field.

Assuming that your primary ID is `tblSessions.session_id`:

```
SELECT d.decisionName, c.firstname, c.lastname, o.name AS organization_name
                                              , s.parent_session_id
FROM   tblDecisions                 d
JOIN   tblSessions                  s ON s.decision_id = d.decisionid
JOIN   tblCounselors                c ON c.campusid = s.counselor_ck
JOIN   tblCounselor_to_organization co ON co.counselor_id = c.counselorid
JOIN   tblOrganizations             o ON o.organizationid = co.organization_id
AND    s.start_time >= '2011-01-01 00:00:00'
AND    s.is_complete
AND    NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   tblSessions s1
    WHERE  s1.parent_session_id = s.session_id
    )
ORDER  BY s.start_time, s.last_name, s.first_name;
```

Your second question *contradicts* the first. So, I'll leave it at that:

> 2.) If multiple records reference the same record in parent_session_id field (> 0), only get the latest one by time stamp (`s.start_time DESC > LIMIT 1`)